# Can you explain the dynamic of forces working in the video?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[Lifting Against Gravity - Breaking Magic - Discovery Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ix9Om81pMQ)

In this video, a woman uses Physics, so that it is difficult to lift her off the ground. The explanation that the video gives at the end is not particularly clear. Therefore, could you explain me the dynamics of all forces acting on her in this situation? A diagram would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First we assume a rigid body system 
The first major reason is that any force force being applied off the center of gravity will cause rotation to occur and in this case it is at many pivots. Namely: her shoulder, her entire body as the force is applied of the CG, and her elbows if not sufficiently locked 
The first time they lifted $$Mg=F_{pull}$$
The second time she was lifted some of the force that was applied went into stabilizing the  torque of the system. As you can see when she if lifted she tend to want to fall backward due to rotation. The rotational intertia of her is actually quite large as $$MR^2=I$$ 
And her mass is quite large

[image]

In general, to lift a real body. One must satisfy rotational and translational equilibrium. In the first case only translational equilibrium is in question 
In the second case rotational equilibrium comes into play with translation

Comment: Tsk, tsk, tsk,  explaining magic tricks:) Seriously,  I am not happy the way the camera shows her full body when she is being lifted, but then zooms in on her, not   showing the same full body shot, when she is "impossible" to lift.

Comment: I understand your pain, this video is meant for the layman and not the inclined physicist. If u see in some cases of the video she falls back and stumbles. Which is consistent with the theory of rotation